# Find $ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{2}{(n+1)^2}+\dots+\frac{n+1}{(2n)^2} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I want to find the following limit: 
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{2}{(n+1)^2}+ \frac{3}{(n+2)^2}+\dots+\frac{n+1}{(2n)^2} $$
I guess it converges to 0 and I tried to prove it using the squeeze theorem but it doesn't seem to work.
Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by $n\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: my mistake, I edited it

Comment: I don’t know if it helps, but this can also be written as $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{x=0}^n\frac{x+1}{(x+n)^2}$$ Sometimes rewriting in sigma notation helps me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your limit can be rewritten as a Riemann sum + $a_n$ where $a_n\rightarrow 0$.

This is a Riemann sum:

\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+ \frac{2}{(n+2)^2}+\dots+\frac{n}{(2n)^2}&=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n}\left ( \frac{1/n}{(1+1/n)^2}+ \frac{2/n}{(1+2/n)^2}+\dots+\frac{n/n}{(1+n/n)^2}\right)\\
&=\int_{0}^1 \frac{x}{(1+x)^2} \text{d}x \\
&=\int_{0}^1 \frac{x+1}{(1+x)^2} \text{d}x -\int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{(1+x)^2} \text{d}x\\
&=\int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{1+x} \text{d}x -\int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{(1+x)^2} \text{d}x
\end{align}

Now,
\begin{align}a_n&=\frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+ \frac{1}{(n+2)^2}+\dots+\frac{1}{(2n)^2} \\
&\leq \frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n^2}+ \frac{1}{n^2}+\dots+\frac{1}{n^2}\\
&=(n+1)\frac{1}{n^2}\rightarrow 0
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although I was looking for something simpler as it adresses to students not familiar with Riemann sums, just basic properties of sequences and limits

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$\frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{2}{(n+1)^2}+ \frac{3}{(n+2)^2}+\dots+\frac{n+1}{(2n)^2}=\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{k-n+1}{k^2}
=\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}-(n-1)\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{1}{k^2}\sim \log \left(\frac{2n}{n-1}\right)-\frac{n+1}{2n}\to\log 2-\frac12$$

indeed for [Harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Harmonic_series_(mathematics)&action=edit&section=6) and [Euler–Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula)

$$\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}\sim\log2n-\log (2n-1)=\log \left(\frac{2n}{n-1}\right)$$

$$\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{1}{k^2}=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k^2}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k^2}\sim -\frac1{2n}+\frac{1}{n-1}=\frac{n+1}{2n(n-1)}$$